# How make external company use cloud function API

Tags: google-cloud-functions

I have cloud functions that are open to all users. I want to authorize any use of these functions.

My case is that I want other companies to access my API but not any other user I have not added.

The documentations from google have not helped me with my specific case.

Is the correct way to do this create a service account for the companies to invoke the API endpoints?

Or should I create a JWT token and verify it somehow? [link](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/openid-connect)

Or do I need to create a Cloud Endpoint Gateway?

OAuth 2 is not suitable since I cannot show the consent screen since it is not a single user.

I'm feeling a bit lost here, thanks for any help! :)

I have tried so many things and none of them works so far, including the ones above. I just want help in the right direction for this case!

Comment: Does the users have a Google Account (workspace, gmail, or something equivalent)?

Comment: Currently, I'm just trying to get it to work with a service account I link to my personal Gmail. To see that it would work for an external user.

Comment: Understood. However, this question is the cornerstone of the solution that you will use. If it's a Google account, you can use IAM service and workspace groups for that. Else, you need to use upper layer solution (such as proxy, API Gateway, ...)

Comment: What is better for future proofing? If I would go for IAM service how would I refresh a new bearer token without a Google consent screen showing up In an Http client?

Comment: For the future, and if you don't manage the identity of your users, it's better to bet on a generic solution and to use API gateway on Google Cloud, or APIGee if you have the budget. You can use Firebase authentication or API Keys. There is a bunch of article on that. let me know if you need some pointers

Comment: Then I will go for a generic solution with API gateway! I guess it is this: [link](https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway) And I guess this is a good start? [link](https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway/docs/get-started-cloud-functions).

Comment: This one also with firebase auth: https://medium.com/@chamaln/setting-up-firebase-token-authentication-with-gcp-api-gateway-1a68578c1eca

Comment: This link was exactly what I wanted! Thank you very much it is working perfectly!

Comment: If you want you can please post an answer and I will accept it as an answer to this question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have 2 solutions to authenticate the users:

- Either you use the IAM service to filter who can access to your service. The tradeoff is the requirement to have a Google account (gmail, workspace,...) and it can't fit to external users use cases (because you can't predict which will be their identity provider)
- Or to use a proxy layer in front of your service, such as API Gateway, or APIGee if you have the budget for.

With API Gateway, you can set up security defition to accept firebase users (great article [here](https://medium.com/@chamaln/setting-up-firebase-token-authentication-with-gcp-api-gateway-1a68578c1eca)) or API Keys (especially for machine to machine communication. I [wrote an article](https://medium.com/google-cloud/secure-cloud-run-cloud-functions-and-app-engine-with-api-key-73c57bededd1) on that with ESPv2, but it's the same concept with API Gateway)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to invite, in your gcp project, some email adresses of these companies - setting their IAM policy role as "Cloud Functions Invoker" ?

Also, there is an "permissions" tab in your Cloud Functions user interface

Don't know if it fits to your case but maybe you'll bounce on that to go further :)

Comment: Currently, I'm using the yyy@yyy.iam.gserviceaccount.com. And it has "Cloud Functions Invoker" role. And I have added the Service account to the Cloud function so it can only be invoked by the owner, and that service account. However I don't seem to get the service account token to be able to attach to the "Bearer". Have any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe that's not good idea for inviting other companies to project. Instead you can provide them access with cors. So it will be much more easy and reliable

Comment: Even though it is a service account, with not access to anything but invoke? Will check out CORS!